# namespace name 'DispatcherTimer' could not be found

Tags: c#, reference, namespaces, .net-assembly, dispatchertimer

I am trying to use a dispatch timer, but my c# app can't find the namespace. This is the error:

> The type or namespace name 'DispatcherTimer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is what I am using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Here is the code:

```
DispatcherTimer timer1 = new DispatcherTimer();
```

Comment: Have you added a reference in the project references for this namespace? According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) `DispatcherTimer` lives in the `System.Windows.Threading` namespace.

Comment: I don't have the option to add that, only choices after system.windows is forms and xps

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) is not a namespace - it's a class within the [`System.Windows.Threading`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms604616.aspx) namespace and the `WindowsBase` assembly. So you need

```
using System.Windows.Threading;
```

In general, a search for the missing type name and "MSDN" is enough to find out where to find a type.

Comment: I don't have the option to add that, only choices after system.windows is forms and xps

Comment: @nate: Then it sounds like you're not writing a WPF or Silverlight app - it sounds like you're writing a Windows Forms app, and `DispatcherTimer` isn't meant for that. Look at `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` instead.

Comment: oh, I thought you could use dispatchertimer in any project type.

Comment: okay, well I guess I will us something else. Thanks for the help

Comment: @nate: I've already suggested the "something else" to use - `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. It's a timer which always fires on the UI thread, which I assume is what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

The Dispatcher class is in WindowsBase.dll. You MUST add that reference to your project to use "using System.Windows.Threading;" <>

Answer (score 1):

Add this using:

```
using System.Windows.Threading;
```

[**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx)

Comment: I don't have the option to add that, only choices after system.windows is forms and xps

Answer (score 0):

Isn't in the System.Windows.Threading namespace and not the System.Threading namespace?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx

Comment: I don't have the option to add that, only choices after system.windows is forms and xps

Answer (score 0):

You must Add WindowsBase in your references so you can use the System.Windows.Threading.